# merge MSO tag [rep-recalc] into [reputation-recalc]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, meta, synonym-request

Suggest to merge MSO tag [rep-recalc](/questions/tagged/rep-recalc) (53 questions as of now) into [reputation-recalc](/questions/tagged/reputation-recalc) (20 questions).

Tags look the same to me. As for tag names, *reputation-recalc* sounds more informative than *rep-recalc*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was as done. Now then make fuller tag wiki with informations. And be of kind to excerpt.

Comment: thanks! I'll upvote tomorrow (out of votes today:). Will check what I can do to tag wiki

Comment: There's less be a need to upvoting these audit of answers

Comment: I just submitted suggested edits for [meta-tag:reputation-recalc] tag wiki and excerpt... and it's already there, thanks to kiamlauno for quick approval!